# deviation in classifier result

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

I saw in some papers that the accuracy of the classifier is a mean accuracy plus and minus some deviation. I was wondering how these deviations come from? For both training set and testing set, everything is deterministic. I do not see where the random part comes from.

Comment: Hard to answer without these papers at hand. But many classifiers are working randomly (taking a seed) and the process of cross-validation (splitting data) is also random and uses a seed.

Comment: I believe you saw something like that in some statistics papers. From statistical point of view we could see a classification error as 2 components - the classification error caused by algorithm itself (it is not fitting to data  100%) and random error which is caused by the fluctuations in the input data as you show the classifier data which it haven't seen before (and which is a bit different from what you trained it on).